# How to click on the text after scroll down in Selenium IDE

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

The web page that I am using has a list of links
My use case is to perform page down operation and select the link at that location.
I performed page down using the following command
storeEval with the Target as selenium.browserbot.getCurrentWindow().scrollTo(0,20000)

The above action performs the page down
My next action is to click the link that is shown

I used the command clickAtAndWait with the target link=target_link

The above action clicks the text target_link at the top of the page (which is not visible) and not the text that is visible.

I need to perform page down and click the text target_link that is visible.
What change needs to be performed for this action?

Answer (score 2):

In the Selenium IDE you can use the Command `focus` with a Target value of an element at the bottom of your page.

For example:

```
Command: focus
Target: id=nextButton1
Value:
```

This will scroll the Selenium IDE (Firefox) window down so the "Next Button" is just visible at the bottom of the screen.  The Value parameter is not used and has been left blank.

Answer (score 0):

You need to find the element and then use the click command.

Sample code:

```
elem1 = driver.find_element_by_class_name("wtb-search-submit")
elem1.click()
```

Read at http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/locating-elements.html on how you can locate the element. Hope it helps.

Comment: I am looking for a solution in Selenium IDE. My entire test suite runs in IDE. Do you know the corresponding action to use in IDE?